# Wireless neteork works fine but problem with Wired connection Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, wired

I can connect to the wireless network just fine.

But when I use a cable, wired network is detected but I cannot access the internet.

Here's the output for ifconfig

```
ifconfig -a 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:1f:af:2b:9c:d6  
      inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f21f:afff:fe2b:9cd6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:14132 (14.1 KB)  TX bytes:18314 (18.3 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7700000-f7720000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22385 (22.3 KB)  TX bytes:22385 (22.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:84:dc:8e:21:eb  
      inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e84:dcff:fe8e:21eb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:91 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12912 (12.9 KB)  TX bytes:13379 (13.3 KB)
```

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your wired network has another subnet. Did you manually set the IP and gateway? Where is the wire connected to? Is it the same router?

Answer (score 0):

Both your adapters, wired and wireless work.

But you can't use them at the same time for internet without special routing setup.

Disconnect or disable your wireless adapter in Network Manager and you will be able to use your wired adapter.

Comment: Doesn't work even after disabling wifi. Any other way to do this. Currently am unchecking enable wifi.